# How can I run a Raspberry Pi compatible MIPI CSI camera on a Rock Pi 4 b?

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, csi

I am trying to run a MIPI CSI camera on a Rock Pi 4 but I can't figure out how to get it working. I have the Rock Pi 4b running on Debian (Linux) and the camera is plugged in and the power LED is lit.

I have found for a Raspberry Pi you type "sudo raspi-config" in the prompt and it opens configuration settings to enable the camera, but I can't find anything similar to work on the Rock Pi 4.

How can I get the camera running/taking video or pictures?

[Camera](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013JWEGJQ)

To clarify: I am not using a Raspberry Pi so Raspberry Pi documentation does not work. I am using a different single board computer called the [Rock Pi 4](https://wiki.radxa.com/Rockpi4).

Comment: I'd try this question on [Raspberry PI.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A quick google "raspberry pi camera tutorial" gives this as the top link: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera

Comment: The problem is that it is a raspberry pi camera but the board I am using is not raspberry pi, it is rock pi 4. The rock pi 4 documentation says it works with the raspi camera but gives no documentation on setup

Comment: I was having same question i am also raspberry pi camera on Rock pi I am getting this error linaro@linaro-alip:~$ test_camera-rkisp1.sh
Start RKISP Camera Preview!
Password:
Setting pipeline to PAUSED …
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
libGL error: unable to load driver: rockchip_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: rockchip
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
libGL error: unable to load driver: rockchip_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: rockchip
Cau

Comment: @Sachin   Please ask this as a new question

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a Rock Pi 4 or a MIPI camera to try it out, but the Rock Pi wiki has an [entry on how to enable MIPI cameras.](https://wiki.radxa.com/Rockpi4/MIPI_Camera)

It says:

> Change /boot/hw_intfc.conf:
>
> Enable IMX219 Camera Module:

```
   # Add imx219 camera module support. Need disabled ov5647 camera module.         
   #intfc:dtoverlay=imx219
```

As a Linux user, that looks slightly wrong.  The second line (`#intfc:dtoverlay=imx219`) should not start with a "#" - that indicates a comment rather than a configuration.

It should probably look like this:

```
   # Add imx219 camera module support. Need disabled ov5647 camera module.         
   intfc:dtoverlay=imx219
```

You need to open the file `/boot/hw_intfc.conf` with a text editor and modify the indicated lines - insert or uncomment as needed.

Comment: The file probably has the line in it already, just commented out, and the edit would be to remove the hash tag.

Comment: @ScottSeidman:  That's what I figure, but the "wiki" is really rudimentary.  It doesn't say to uncomment the line.  It just has the configuration lines and above that "Enable IMX219 Camera Module."